# How to solve Elements with an ARIA [role] that require children to contain a specific [role] are missing some or all of those required children?

Tags: magento2, pagespeed, google

Anyone knows how to resolve below error from Google pagespeed score for Magento2 website.

ARIA Elements with an ARIA [role] that require children to contain a specific [role] are missing some or all of those required children.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Accessible Rich Internet Applications** (ARIA) is a set of roles and attributes that define ways to make web content and web applications (especially those developed with JavaScript) more accessible to people with disabilities.

There are a lot of other aria roles which are required to have children with specific roles nested within it.
In this specific case, ARIA role attribute is added to an element to instruct assistive technologies to treat the element as something other than its native HTML element type. For example, a `<ul>` element with `role="listbox"` is to be treated as a listbox control, not as a static list.

So, in your case `<div class="section-items nav-sections-items mage-tabs-disabled" role="tablist">` must have elements nested within it which contain `role="tab"`.

Following are the examples of more of the elements which required to have children with specific roles nested within them to work properly.

**Example 1 - listitem**

This element with the `list` role only owns elements with the listitem role. The **listitem** role is one of the required owned elements for list.

```
<div role="list">
    <span role="listitem">Item 1</span>
    <span role="listitem">Item 2</span>
</div>
```

This element with the list role only owns elements with the listitem role through the **aria-owns** attribute. The listitem role is one of the required owned elements for list.

**Note:** This test case follows the definition of owned by. If implemented differently, this definition could cause differences in outcome of this test case.

```
<div role="list" aria-owns="id1"></div>
<div id="id1" role="listitem">Item 1</div>
```

**Example 2 - grid**

This element with the **grid** role only owns elements with the `row` role, and the element with the `row` role only owns elements with the `cell` role. The row role is one of the required owned elements for grid, and cell is one of the required owned elements for row.

```
<table role="grid">
    <tr role="row">
        <td role="cell">Item 1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Example 3 - menuitem**

This element with the menu role only owns elements with the **menuitem**, `menuitemradio` and `menuitemcheckbox` role. These roles are all required owned elements for menu. The element with the none role is not owned by the menu because it is not included in the accessibility tree.

```
<div role="menu">
    <li role="none"></li>
    <li role="menuitem">Item 1</li>
    <div role="menuitemradio" aria-checked="false">Item 2</div>
    <div role="menuitemcheckbox" aria-checked="false">Item 3</div>
</div>
```

**Example 4 - tablist**

This element with the tablist role only owns elements with the `tab` role. The tab role is one of the required owned elements for tablist. The li element is ignored because it has an explicit semantic role of none.

```
<ul role="tablist">
    <li role="none">
        <span role="tab">Tab 1</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Example 5 - group**

This element with the menu role only owns an element with a **group** role. The group in turn owns an element with the `menuitem` role, and an element with the group role, in which each element has the `menuitem` role. ARIA group roles are allowed to own other elements with a group role.

```
<div role="menu">
    <div role="group">
        <span role="menuitem">Item 1</span>
        <div role="group">
            <span role="menuitem">Item 2</span>
            <span role="menuitem">Item 3</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**References**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA
- https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#mustContain
- https://accessibilityinsights.io/info-examples/web/aria-required-children/
- https://www.w3.org/WAI/standards-guidelines/act/rules/bc4a75/proposed/